# Simplest jQuery Masonry Script

Tags: jquery

I looking-for script like jQuery Masonry, but very simplest.
Interested me only stacking images without animation, events, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with Masonry? It is absolutely tiny: http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js

Comment: I would also recommend Masonry - small, effective and updadted. http://masonry.desandro.com/ - Isotope is awesome too, but much more bloated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need (from https://gist.github.com/2208329):

```
(function($) {
    // Finding min and max values in array
    Array.prototype.min = function() {return Math.min.apply({},this);};
    Array.prototype.max = function() {return Math.max.apply({},this);};
    $.fn.masonry = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var wall = $(this);
            if (wall.children().length > 0) { // Check if the element has anything in it
                if (wall.children('.masonry-wrap').length === 0) { // checks if the `.masonry-wrap` div is already there
                    wall.wrapInner('<div class="masonry-wrap"></div>');
                }
                var m_w = wall.children('.masonry-wrap'),
                    brick = m_w.children(),
                    b_w = brick.outerWidth(true),
                    c_c = Math.floor(m_w.width() / b_w),
                    c_h = [], this_col, i;
                for (i = 0; i < c_c; i++) {
                    c_h[i] = 0;
                }
                m_w.css('position', 'relative');
                brick.css({
                    'float':'none',
                    'position':'absolute',
                    'display':'block'
                }).each(function() {
                    for (i = c_c - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        if (c_h[i] == c_h.min()) {
                            this_col = i;
                        }
                    }
                    $(this).css({
                        'top':c_h[this_col],
                        'left':b_w * this_col
                    });
                    c_h[this_col] += $(this).outerHeight(true);
                });
                m_w.height(c_h.max()).parent().addClass('start-transition');
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

---

#### Update

Created the pure JavaScript version here → https://github.com/tovic/bricks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but I've written a bin-packing algorithm for a client and in essence the masonry script can do the same. What I don't know is how the masonry script can handle multicolumn bricks or bricks that span more then a column. A simple solution would be to ignore the width in the minimize function and then fiddle around with the result and the other columns. In general you can look for a 1d bin-packing algorithm, for example first-fit, best-fit, last-fit, worst-fit. You can combine it with different sorting ascendent, descendent and random. Or you can write an optimal solution by yourself but the problem is np-complete and this means you must check n! possibilites to stack your images. Even with a compiler language and a fast pc this can take some time.